# Page is not responsive after implementing in wordpress

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a responsive HTML page. when I implement this HTML page in Wordpress with all the contents static in `index.php`. Without including `header` and `footer`, the home page is responsive.

But when I include header and footer to make the theme dynamic it is not responsive any more.

When I comment the `wp_head()` function it again become responsive.

So what is the issue here, How can I make my theme responsive?

Here is my header file when theme is responsive:

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
```

**UPDATED**

Here is my source after including wp_head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>


    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="vertaxwordpress &raquo; Feed" href="http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="vertaxwordpress &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='open-sans-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%3A300italic%2C400italic%2C600italic%2C300%2C400%2C600&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext&#038;ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=3.9.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css'  href='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-content/themes/vertaxtheme/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-style-css'  href='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-content/themes/vertaxtheme/style.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-ie-css'  href='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-content/themes/vertaxtheme/css/ie.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9.1" />
<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" id="twentythirteen-header-css">
    .site-header {
    background: url(http://192.168.1.101/vertaxwordpress/wp-content/themes/vertaxtheme/images/headers/circle.png) no-repeat scroll top;
    background-size: 1600px auto;
    }
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can provide the header when wp_head is included that would help a lot.

Comment: @AlpeshShah I have updated the question see the source code above. Thanks